# disable ui-select-choices after selecting two items from the ui-select unless user removes atleast one item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

Disable ui-select-choices after selecting two items from the ui-select unless user removes atleast one item. This code works great for multiselect. limit attribute not working. So, I used on-select to alert the user if they select more than 2 items. But the requirement is to limit 2 and disable the choices. How do we do that?

```
 <ui-select multiple ng-model="cModel.selectedCountries" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" theme="bootstrap" on-select="someFunction($item, $model)">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select ..." allow-clear="true">{{$item.name}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="country.id as country in countryCodes | filter:$select.search">
                                    {{ country.name }}
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what are you looking for

```js
<ui-select multiple limit="2" ng-model="cModel.selectedCountries" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" theme="bootstrap" on-select="someFunction($item, $model)">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select ..." allow-clear="true">{{$item.name}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="country.id as country in countryCodes | filter:$select.search">
                                    {{ country.name }}
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
```

Comment: I will be the happiest person if the limit attribute works. But, no, the limit attribute is not working.Yes, I am looking for that functionality only. Since limit is not working, I am trying to do mimic that feature manually.